# Increase a value like = +1 in mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with this.

I am making a login and when a user insert a bad answer i want that my system take the valor of the column in the database and this adds the value of the base + 1

I try making this

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE usuarios_empleados  set intentos = + 1 where usuario = ?";
$params2 = array ($this->nickname);
return Database::executeRow($sql2, $params2);
```

Comment: Did you try it with the column value `+ 1`?  e.g. `intentos = intentos+ 1`

Comment: Yes i try this "UPDATE `usuarios_empleados` SET `intentos` = (`intentos` + 1) where `id_usuario_empleado` = 3" but doesn´t increase the value

Comment: if that query `intentos = (intentos + 1)` didn't work, then there's something else wrong.  That query should definitely do it. Check if your prepared statement works as it should, or if it fails for some other reason

Answer (score 0):

Please try this line, hope it will be work

```
"UPDATE usuarios_empleados SET intentos = intentos + 1 where id_usuario_empleado = your_value"
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE usuarios_empleados  set intentos = (intentos + 1) where usuario = ?

Answer (score -1):

You have to first make a SELECT and see the value of the column "intentos". Then you will do the UPDATE using the value from the SELECT + 1

Comment: You don't need a `select` first.

Comment: Yes. You are right. As you said you can use intentos = intentos+ 1

Comment: I make this "UPDATE `usuarios_empleados` SET `intentos` = (`intentos` + 1) where `id_usuario_empleado` = 3"